# How to automatically send a scheduled notification everyday in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an app that needs to send a reminder notification everyday at a user specified time. For now, I have used [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and used the `zoneSchedule` method to send a notification locally for that particular day after fetching the time from firebase.

My question is how should I make it so that this notification is sent everyday? When should the scheduling happen.
The specified time can be changed by the user.

I'd like the notification to be sent even when there is no internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

If the app is not in the foreground the app is suspended, so your code wont execute.

You can wake up the app via a push notification from an external source but this will not work if the app has no internet connection.

If you want to execute it without an internet connection, you have to register a background task.

See:

- https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes
- https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

Comment: What kind of external source will you suggest? I am using Firebase so can such task be configured via Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Comment: As I have written, triggering the notification externally (e.g. firebase) does not work without an internet connection.
If you still want to use firebase you need some program running on a server which will send the notification via firebase,

Comment: So that means external server code is required? I was hoping to get things done with Firebase alone.

Comment: if you want to use firebase you need a server application. but maybee you get away with the background process running on the device